# How to get wialon login user Unit list

Tags: ios, api, mobile, sdk, location

How to get login user Unit list with all details, any APi doc provided by Wialon

1. Login User Unit list with all details same as location, Time, Speed, Engine status and all
2. History of the unit datewise
3. Get Report details of the unit from between dates
4. Notifications
5. Set Geo-Location and get report details of the units
6. Setting, to get notifications or not,
7. Unit location history

Found Remote API from here but count not get specific API on this https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/sidebar/remoteapi/apiref/apiref

https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/local/remoteapi1904/apiref/format/token#unlimited_operation_as_authorizated_user

Please let me know any support

Comment: The API Docs http://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/sidebar/remoteapi/apiref/apiref

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions.
First you need a valid 72 character Token generated from the application you will login using the following query

```
https://hst-api.wialon.com/ajax.html?params={"token":"<TOKEN>"}&svc=token/login
```

Use the 'eid' from the result as Session ID (sid)
Session will expire within 2 minutes of inactivity

I would suggest that you build a report on Wialon and query the report template instead of parsing the messages. This can be very tedious.

To Query for all available Units:

```
https://hst-api.wialon.com/wialon/ajax.html?params={"spec":{"itemsType":"avl_unit","propName":"sys_name","propValueMask":"*","sortType":"sys_name"},"force":1,"flags":13644935,"from":0,"to":4294967295}&svc=core/search_items&sid=<SID>
```